# OpenCV in C# UWP app?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, win-universal-app

I have a C# project UWP app project. I added a C++ windows runtime component that has my openCV code. My method in c++ returns a writeable bitmap and to call it from c# I am using Dll import.

When I try to run the app, following exception occurs

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in uwp1.exe
```

Is it possible to return a WriteableBitmap^ in c++ runtime component and store it in a WriteableBitmap in C#?

If I am doing something very wrong,  please tell me what is it that I am doing wrong before downvoting my question.

Comment: Do you have an inner exception with more details? For .NET there used to be a C# wrapper library EmguCV

Comment: EmguCV for windows phone app developement has a commercial license only. So, I need to figure out something else.

Comment: I think OpenCV for WinRT might help. Check [this](https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/08/20/opencv-support-for-windows-universal-apps-now-available-on-github/) out

Comment: I already tried that, I was able to use opencv with a c++ windows phone app but my app is c# xaml app. So for the c++ RT component to show images, according to me, will be very difficult.